# Video subscription in iOS with external payment gateways

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway

Can I use external payment gateways for video subscription (eg: Live channels),without using Apple In-app purchase ? According to Apple review guidline :

```
Apps utilising a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use any external payment gateway for this use case.
Since you are unlocking a digital feature to the user in your app, based on the subscription, it has to go through Apple IAP.